# Integrar Laravel 5 Apache en linux

Tags: php, laravel, linux, apache, ubuntu

Buenas Estoy tratando de integrar laravel y apache pero las rutas no me las reconoce el apache.

Bueno muestro la configuracion que tengo

en el virtutalHost del apache2 tengo

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  #Alias /loginseg /var/www/html/otro/laravel/public
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/otro/laravel/public"
  <Directory "/var/www/html/otro/laravel/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
 </Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

y en el .htaccess del public del proyecto es

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSysmLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Authorization Headers
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

la pagina principal funciona perfectamente pero cuando ingreso a una ruta diferente al index se genera el error Not Found

**Actualizacion**
Alfin quedo solucionado con lo que Xerif indico con el a2enmod rewrite

Recursos relacionados http://blog.furiosojack.com/2017/04/integrar-apache-y-laravel-solucion-http.html

Comment: Tienes activada la reescritura de url (mod_rewrite) en apache? Puedes activarlo con el siguiente comando **a2enmod rewrite**

Comment: Cuando descargas _Laravel_ en la carpeta **public** hay un **.htacces** por defecto. ¿Estás usando ese el que se descarga por defecto?, y yo en el _Virtual Host_ solo lo tengo con la condición `AllowOverride All` y me funciona bien, prueba quitando las otras dos condiciones y comentas si te funciona.

Comment: es correcto ha quedado solicionado @Xerif

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para que laravel funcione correctamente debes activar el módulo de reescritura de url en apache  (mod_rewrite).

Para hacerlo puedes  utilizar el siguiente comando:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Después debes reiniciar apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```