# Error 404 al acceder a mi virtual host

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Buenas tardes estoy aprendiendo a usar Laravel y para eso estoy realizando un proyecto, el problema es que cuando trato de acceder a mi virtual host me muestra un error 404.

tengo las siguientes rutas en el archivo routes/web.php:

```
Route::redirect('/', 'icj');
Route::get('icj', 'Web\PageController@icj')->name('icj');
```

y en el controlador tengo solo este código:

```
public function icj()
{
    return 'Bienvenidos';
}
```

Antes de agregar esas nuevas rutas funcionaba todo bien, la ruta que traía era:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

el problema es que ahora ya ni poniendo esa ruta me funciona.

Nota 1: el virtual host apunta hacia mi directorio "public" del proyecto en Laravel donde se encuentra el archivo "index.php" lo extraño es que si cambio la url por "http://ejemplo.com/**index.php**" si funciona.

Comment: Roman, el webserver es un apache2 o un nginx? Estas seguro que habilitaste la reescritura de rutas? Porque vas a necesitar indicar en tu vhost que todo lo que caiga en "icj.com" vaya directamente a index.php.
Estaria bueno que compartas tu vhost

Comment: Seguite estos pasos si tenes [apache](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost) o estos si tenes [nginx](https://gist.github.com/enginkartal/04d727d361382dc3d41b)

Comment: Muchas gracias @SebastianPortesi, efectivamente no había habilitado el modulo para la reescritura de rutas, lo habilite y ya funciona correctamente.

Comment: @SebastianPortesi desarrolla una respuesta Sebastian y agregala para que Román la marque como solución!.

Comment: @RomanGonzález   Revisa esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71658/integrar-laravel-5-apache-en-linux/71953#71953 seguramente no tienes activado el `mod rewrite`

Answer (score 0):

Cambia los permisos de los directorios /public, /storage y /bootstrap a 777.

Ejecutando: `sudo chmod 777 -R /public`