# error al instalar un servidor web en Opensuse con laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, linux, apache2, opensuse

quiero poner un proyecto de laravel en un servidor web en linux, anteriormente lo estuve en desarrollando en windows.

estoy utilizando opensuse
instalé el servidor LAMP

puse mi carpeta de laravel en la ruta **/srv/www/htdocs**

creé el enlace simbólico, **php artisan storage:link**

Le di permisos ala carpeta

```
php artisan clear-compiled
chmod -R 777 storage
chmod -R 777 boostrap/cache
composer dum-autoload
```

edite el archivo httpd.conf y le añadí el directorio

> ```
> <VirtualHost *>
>      ServerName www.prueba1.com
>      DocumentRoot "/srv/www/htdocs/incidencias_pc/public"
>   <Directory /srv/www/htdocs/incidencias_pc/public>
>         AllowOverride none
>         Require all granted
>   </Directory>
>      </VirtualHost>
> ```

cree mi base de datos y edite el archivo .env de laravel

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=imagenes
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

al acceder ala pagina no me cargan los estilos 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al intertar acceder al sistema me aparece el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para descartar que no sea un problema de permisos prueba con los de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/269243/92278). Nota que nunca deberías usar 777, pues le estarías dando permiso de escritura a todo el mundo. En adición a los permisos, también debes asignar cual es el usuario y grupo al que pertenecen archivos y directorios.

Comment: Ya lo revisé e hice las pruebas, aun me sigue sin cargar los estilos y no hay conexión con mysql

Comment: Revisa los logs de apache, para ver si tienes algún error `/var/log/apache2`.

Comment: tambié te puede servir esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/71953/92278